# Is there any way to update variable with value while sending HTTP request

Tags: json, http, testing, jmeter

I have a JSON file which contains some variables, as it needs to update with values which is a response from previous request. Is there any way to do that?

I tried to send the request normally but it's not working. So, How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you're sending the file. If you're using i.e. [__FileToString() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) - it's sufficient to wrap it into [__eval() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__eval) additionally so any JMeter Functions or Variables will be replaced with their respective values.

In case you're sending the file via Files Upload tab of the HTTP Request sampler you can re-write the variables placeholders with the actual values using i.e. [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy).